# NoMethodError in SectionsController#index trying to nest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-management-system

I am trying to nest `Sections` into `Page` in my training code and I get this error:

```
undefined method `sections' for nil:NilClass
```

Before this, I nested my `Page` in `Subjects` successfully.

See the error in this picture below trying to nest Sections into Page.

[image: Error]

Here is what I have done:

sections_controller.rb:

```
class SectionsController < ApplicationController

  layout 'admin'

  before_action :confirm_logged_in
  before_action :find_page

  def index
    @sections = @page.sections.sorted
  end

  private

    def find_page
      if params[:page_id]
        @page = Page.find(params[:page_id])
      end
    end
end
```

My View:

index.html.erb:

```
<% @page_title = 'Sections' %>

<%= link_to('<< Back to Pages', {:controller => 'pages', :action => 'index', :subject_id => @page.subject_id}, :class => 'back-link') %>

<div class="sections index">
  <h2>Sections</h2>

  <%= link_to('Add New Section', {:action => 'new', :page_id => @page.id, :page_id => @page.id}, :class => 'action new') %>

  <table class="listing" summary="Section list">
    <tr class="header">
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>Page</th>
      <th>Section</th>
      <th>Content Type</th>
      <th>Visible</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
    <% @sections.each do |section| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= section.position %></td>
      <td><%= section.page.name if section.page %></td>
      <td><%= section.name %></td>
      <td><%= section.content_type %></td>
      <td class="center"><%= status_tag(section.visible) %></td>
      <td class="actions">
        <%= link_to('Show', {:action => 'show', :id => section.id, :page_id => @page.id}, :class => 'action show') %>
        <%= link_to('Edit', {:action => 'edit', :id => section.id, :page_id => @page.id}, :class => 'action edit') %>
        <%= link_to('Delete', {:action => 'delete', :id => section.id, :page_id => @page.id}, :class => 'action delete') %>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: From what page are you trying to call the `index` action of your section controller? I.e. the link you clicked before you got that error. Can you show us your code for the link?

Comment: @SunnyK, I am calling it directly as per from my route with this URL. http://127.0.0.1:3000/sections

Comment: If I remove all nestings, its works. As a CMS, I am nesting sections into Page so as to have only related record in my CMS. Let me paste the code without nesting which worked once I http://127.0.0.1:3000/sections

Comment: you are not passing any page_id in that url, and that is why the @page is nil. Please take a look at my answer below. You either need to nest the sections in the page, or you need to call the url like this: http://127.0.0.1:3000/sections?page_id=1

Comment: @bosskovic http://127.0.0.1:3000/sections?page_id=2 works without any error. But i will still like http://127.0.0.1:3000/sections to work. Do you advice....

Comment: well if you want in you sections index to list the sections of particular page, then you will need to somehow tell what page is it. You can do what I proposed below, and it would result in a link like this: http://127.0.0.1:3000/pages/2/sections

Comment: or if you are happy to show any sections, not related to particular page, then please change you index to this: `@sections = Sections.all.sorted`

Comment: Yes it worked as you advised. I did need nest the sections in the page. 
Thanks @bosskovic 
Though it left me with a small glitch. I created a button for it that takes me to the nested section from page. After clicking/viewing it, my Back-Link didnt take me back to http://127.0.0.1:3000/sections?page_id=2 where I left.

Comment: it took me to http://127.0.0.1:3000/sections?page_id=1 instead.
here is my Back-Link:
<%= link_to('<< Back to Pages', {:controller => 'pages', :action => 'index', :subject_id => @page.subject_id}, :class => 'back-link') %>

@bosskovic, I like to be versatile and swift with Rails. Kindly advice me on books to read or resources I can still learn from. Thanks

Comment: please open up the terminal, navigate to your project dir and run this: `rake routes`; it will show you all routes available for your application. The first column represents the name of the route, and you can also use the path helpers by appending "_path" to the route name. More details about it here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: I suggest that you read other guides on that site as well. This is fun way to learn rails: http://railsforzombies.org/ . This course is also good, if you need to get acquainted with ruby: https://www.codeschool.com/courses/try-ruby .  Here you can find many topics about rails: http://railscasts.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, lets go step by step; first you navigate to the Sections index route, and this is the code for the index action:

```
def index
  @sections = @page.sections.sorted
end
```

You also have a `before_action :find_page` that is supposed to set the `@page`:

```
def find_page
  if params[:page_id]
    @page = Page.find(params[:page_id])
  end
end
```

but this never happens because either `params[:page_id]` is **nil** or there is no Page that has the id that you passed. So, @page is nil, and you call nil.sections and the exception you posted is triggered.

How do you pass `page_id`, as an url parameter?

Is it possible that you actually intended something like this in the routes:

```
resources :pages do
  resources :sections
end
```

If so, the correct section index route would look like this:

```
page_sections GET  /pages/:page_id sections(.:format)   sections#index
```

Comment: nice insight. http://127.0.0.1:3000/sections?page_id=2 did work and populated my sections page. But I will still like http://127.0.0.1:3000/sections to be functional. 

This is all I have in my route.rb

get 'admin', :to => 'access#index'  
match ':controller(/:action(/:id))', :via => [:get, :post]

Comment: You have a solution, but I still cant get the solution here to work

Comment: please write what you tried, and what the error is. Did you adapt the routes?